# Definir lista dentro de matriz

Tags: python, lista, matrices

Me gustaría poder crear una variable que fuera una matriz N x N y que cada uno de las posiciones de la matriz fuese una lista de dos elementos.

y poder asignarlos de una forma similar a esto, dentro de un bucle `for`:

```
matriz[1][2]=[345.545, 415.213]
```

¿Cómo defino la variable matriz? 
He intentando con algo como:

```
matriz = np.array(N,N), dtype=list)
```

pero no funciona bien.

Comment: ¿`matriz[1][2] = list([345.545, 415.231])`?

Comment: Me refiero a poder decir el elemento en la posicon 1, 2 va a contener una lista con valores [x, y] los que sean.

Comment: Algo así: `matriz = list([ [] for i in range(1, N) ] for k in range(1, N))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es acceder a un `list` o un `array` con el operador `[][]`, solo debes meter una lista dentro de otra lista, en Python 2 y 3 se puede hacer de la misma forma:

```
# Suponiendo que N sean 10 items:
N = 10
# Creamos la lista de NxN listas.
matriz = list([ list([]) for i in range(0, N) ] for k in range(0, N)) 
matriz[1][2] = [ 345.545, 415.213 ]
print(matriz) # imprime la lista.
```

Debería imprimir:

```
[
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [345.545, 415.213], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 1):

Si no me he confundido lo que deseas es un array de tres dimensiones, es decir, una matriz de NxN donde cada elemento es un array/lista de una dimensión con dos elementos. Ya que trabajas con NumPy deberias usar un `np.array` y no una lista para cada elemento de la matriz. Puedes iniciar tu matriz con todos los eleemntos a 0 usando [`numpy.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 3
>>> matriz = np.zeros((N,N,2))
>>> matriz[1][2]=[345.545, 415.213]
>>> matriz
array([[[   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [   0.   ,    0.   ]],

       [[   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [ 345.545,  415.213]],

       [[   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [   0.   ,    0.   ],
        [   0.   ,    0.   ]]])
```